# Generar fechas aleatorias

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando un programa que genera fechas aleatoriamente y las imprime, si la fecha cae en un día festivo, imprime un mensaje tal como: ¡Feliz Halloween!
Ahora, si el mes elegido es febrero y el día es uno que febrero no tiene, como 29, 30 o 31, se le resta 3 al día. Lo mismo con los demás meses que sólo tienen 30 días.
Pero me resulta tedioso ejecutar la función cada vez que quiero que se genere una fecha, entonces quiero que al principio del programa, me pregunte por la cantidad de fechas que quiero que se generen, y que las imprima a una lista, todas al azar.

He aquí el programa:

```
import random
def fechas():
#La lista de meses y días posibles

meses = ["enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"]
dias = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]

#Elije un mes y un día al azar

m = random.choice(meses) 
d = random.choice(dias)

#Si a ciertos meses se le asigna un día más alto se le resta 3 o 1 al día.

if m == "febrero" and d == 31 or d == 30 or d == 29:
    d = (d)-3
if m == "abril" and d == 31:
    d = (d)-1
if m == "junio" and d == 31:
    d = (d)-1
if m == "septiembre" and d == 31:
    d = (d)-1
if m == "noviembre" and d == 31:
    d = (d)-1

#Si la fecha coincide con una festiva, imprime un mensaje

if m == "enero" and d == 1:
    print("¡Feliz año nuevo!")
if m == "octubre" and d == 31:
    print("¡Feliz Halloween!")
if m == "diciembre" and d == 24:
    print("¡Feliz navidad!")
print(str(d) + " de " + str(m) + ".")
```

Quiero saber cómo hacer lo dicho anteriormente, y que automáticamente genere la cantidad de fechas que yo quiera.

Answer (score 2):

Para facilitar un poco el tema con los días de cada mes podrías usar el módulo [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html). Usando la función `monthrange` cuyo segundo parámetro retorna la cantidad de días del mes (como los días de febrero para años bisiestos):

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.monthrange(month=2, year=2017)
(2, 28)
>>> calendar.monthrange(month=2, year=2020) # Bisiesto
(5, 29)
>>> calendar.monthrange(month=12, year=2020)
(1, 31)
```

Por cierto, el primer parámetro es el día de la semana del primer día del mes (contando desde 0 como lunes). Con la cantidad de días del mes vas a poder validar el día correcto como verás más adelante.

Me parece que también te vas a complicar si trabajas con los meses como texto en vez de números (eso lo puedes formatear después):

```
>>> dias = range(1, 32) # No se incluye el 32
>>> meses = range(1, 13) # No se incluye el 13
```

Para los días festivos puedes mapear las fechas que quieras como tuplas del tipo `(mes, dia)` o `(dia, mes)` como prefieras:

```
>>> festividades = {
...   (1, 1): '¡Feliz año nuevo!',
...   (31, 10): '¡Feliz Halloween!',
...   (25, 12): '¡Feliz Navidad!'
... }
```

Juntando un poco todo en un script:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import calendar
from datetime import date, datetime
import random


def fechas(dia=None, mes=None):
    mensajes_festivos = {
        (1, 1): '¡Feliz año nuevo!',
        (31, 10): '¡Feliz Halloween!',
        (25, 12): '¡Feliz Navidad!'
    }
    hoy = date.today()

    # Si no hemos pasado el día o el mes en la función seleccionamos un al azar
    if not dia:
        dia = random.choice(range(1, 32))
    if not mes:
        mes = random.choice(range(1, 13))

    # Hay que usar el día válido, verifiquemos que no se pase del rango. No nos
    # interesa por ahora el primer parámetro retornado, solo la cantidad de días
    # del mes
    _, dia_maximo = calendar.monthrange(year=hoy.year, month=mes)
    if dia > dia_maximo:
        dia = dia_maximo

    # El mensaje final es una mezcla del mensaje festivo junto con el mensaje de
    # la descripción del día. Si no hay día destivo mapeado simplemente no se
    # imprime nada
    fecha = date(hoy.year, mes, dia)
    mensaje = [
        fecha.strftime('%d de %B del %Y')
    ]
    mensaje_festivo = mensajes_festivos.get((dia, mes), '')
    if mensaje_festivo:
        mensaje.append(mensaje_festivo)

    # Mostrar mensaje
    print(' '.join(mensaje))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fechas() # Sin parámetros, dia y mes al azar
    fechas(dia=31, mes=10) # Probemos con Halloween
    fechas()
    fechas(dia=31, mes=2) # ¿31 de febrero? Hmm, no.
    fechas(dia=25, mes=12) # ¿Qué tal con Navidad?
```

Mi script se llama prueba.py, vamos a ejecutarlo:

```
$ python3 test.py
02 de May del 2017
31 de October del 2017 ¡Feliz Halloween!
20 de February del 2017
28 de Frebruary del 2017
25 de December del 2017 ¡Feliz Navidad!
```

Funciona pero ¡ugh!... está en inglés. Puedes usar el maravilloso [`babel`](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/) para solucionar este problema.

```
$ sudo pip3 install babel
Collecting babel
  Downloading Babel-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.8MB 85kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=0a in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from babel)
Installing collected packages: babel
Successfully installed babel-2.5.1
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from babel.dates import format_date
>>> from datetime import date
>>> format_date(date(2017, 10, 31), locale='es')
'31 oct. 2017'
>>> format_date(date(2017, 10, 31), format='long', locale='es')
'31 de octubre de 2017'
```

¡Excelente! Ahora solo hay que agregarlo al script y tenemos todo listo (esta vez sin todos los comentarios):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import calendar
from babel.dates import format_date
from datetime import date, datetime
import random


def fechas(dia=None, mes=None):
    mensajes_festivos = {
        (1, 1): '¡Feliz año nuevo!',
        (31, 10): '¡Feliz Halloween!',
        (25, 12): '¡Feliz Navidad!'
    }
    hoy = date.today()

    if not dia:
        dia = random.choice(range(1, 32))
    if not mes:
        mes = random.choice(range(1, 13))

    _, dia_maximo = calendar.monthrange(year=hoy.year, month=mes)
    if dia > dia_maximo:
        dia = dia_maximo

    fecha = date(hoy.year, mes, dia)
    mensaje = [
        format_date(fecha, format='long', locale='es_PE')
    ]
    mensaje_festivo = mensajes_festivos.get((dia, mes), '')
    if mensaje_festivo:
        mensaje.append(mensaje_festivo)

    print(' '.join(mensaje))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fechas() # Sin parámetros, dia y mes al azar
    fechas(dia=31, mes=10) # Probemos con Halloween
    fechas()
    fechas(dia=31, mes=2) # ¿31 de febrero? Hmm, no.
    fechas(dia=25, mes=12) # ¿Qué tal con Navidad?
```

Vemos ahora:

```
$ python3 test.py 
26 de julio de 2017
31 de octubre de 2017 ¡Feliz Halloween!
9 de mayo de 2017
28 de febrero de 2017
25 de diciembre de 2017 ¡Feliz Navidad!
```

Todo listo.

Answer (score 2):

En cuanto a tu código, tienes ya casi todo resuelto, lo único que deberías hacer es lo siguiente:

```
cant = int(input("Cantidad de Fechas a generar:"))
for i in range(cant):
  fechas()
```

Es decir, le solicitamos al usuario una cantidad de fechas por teclado, mediante [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#input), debemos convertirlo a un número entero (usando [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int)), por que el retorno es una cadena. Luego simplemente un ciclo `for` para iterar las veces solicitadas, para eso usamos [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-range) que es un generador de secuencias y nos dará el conjunto de números de `0` a `n-1`. Luego simplemente invocamos tu rutina. Si quisieras guardar todos los datos en una lista, deberías hacer que `fecha()` retorne el texto en vez de imprimirlo por pantalla, para eso deberías asignarlos valores que imprimes a una variable y retornarla de la función, luego simplemente la vas agregando a una lista, o también podrías resolverlo todo en la función...

Algunos temas de implementación los resolvería de otra forma, veamos:

1. Los `if` para poder ajustar la cantidad de días se podría resolver si previamente contamos con la lista de fechas ya generada
2. Las fechas festivas se pueden manejar mejor en un diccionario para evitar también el uso de tantos `if`.
3. Lo otro que me hace "ruido" es hacer un random sobre días y meses, por que no es una distribución uniforme, hay días que aparecen más que otros y además si eventualmente pides un año entero, es muy probable que se repitan días.

Por todo esto, te cuento como implementaría tu rutina:

```
from random import shuffle
import datetime

def fechas(year=2017, cantidad=1):
  base = datetime.datetime(year,1,1)
  date_list = [(d.month, d.day) for d in [base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 366)] if d.year == year]

  meses = ["enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"]

  fiestas = {(1,1):"¡Feliz año nuevo!",
            (12,25):"¡Feliz navidad!",
            (10,31):"¡Feliz Halloween!"
  }

  lista_fechas = []
  shuffle(date_list)
  for _ in range(cantidad):
    f = date_list.pop()
    fiesta = fiestas.get((f[0], f[1]), "")
    fiesta = fiesta + "\n" if fiesta else ""
    lista_fechas.append("{0}{1} de {2}.".format(fiesta, str(f[1]), meses[f[0]-1]))

  return lista_fechas

cant = int(input("Cantidad de Fechas a generar:"))
print(fechas(cantidad=cant))
```

Algunos comentarios:

```
  base = datetime.datetime(year,1,1)
  date_list = [(d.month, d.day) for d in [base + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 366)] if d.year == year]
```

Con el código anterior generamos una lista de tuplas `(mes, día)` de un año completo, del año que le digamos, la función recibe el parámetro `year` que por defecto es `2017`, al finalizar en `date_list` vamos a tener una lista del tipo `[(1,1), (1,2) ... (12,31)]`. Contemplamos también los años que sean bisiestos. Para todo esto nos apoyamos en ([timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20timedelta#datetime.timedelta)): `base + datetime.timedelta`  que nos devolverá un desplazamiento, en este caso de días desde la fecha `base` y tomando como intervalo un `range(0, 366)`.

Las fechas festivas las manejamos como un diccionario, cada clave se corresponde con alguna de las tuplas anteriores, de manera que si un valor aleatorio corresponde a la tupla `(1,1)` de manera rápida y eficiente podemos a obtener la cadena correspondiente a la festividad `(1,1):"¡Feliz año nuevo!"`.

El otro tema distinto a tu implementación es que en vez de randomizar días y meses, usamos una rutina del módulo [random](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html?highlight=shuffle#random.shuffle): `shuffle(date_list)` para desordenar de forma aleatoria la lista de fechas completa. De manera que luego, simplemente iteramos hasta la cantidad de fechas pedidas y recuperamos un valor y lo quitamos de la lista mediante `f = date_list.pop()` con esto nos aseguramos que si pedimos 365 o 366 valores nunca obtendremos un valor repetido. Luego simplemente agregamos este valor a una lista junto el eventual mensaje de día festivo:

```
fiesta = fiestas.get((f[0], f[1]), "")
fiesta = fiesta + "\n" if fiesta else ""
lista_fechas.append("{0}{1} de {2}.".format(fiesta, str(f[1]), meses[f[0]-1]))
```

Al finalizar tendremos una lista `lista_fechas` que contendrá las fechas en el formato planteado en tu pregunta y eventualmente el mensaje de salutación de la festividad. (por ahora todo concatenado para respetar tu pregunta pero puedes elegir cualquier otra forma de mostrar estos datos).